# Constrained combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

You are to group numbers from $1$ to $N$. You can only group adjacent numbers (difference of $1$), and you are also given with a set of pairs of numbers that conflict and should not be present in a group. Also a group can contain a single integer as such. You can also take consecutive strings of arbitrary length.

For ex: If $(1,3)$ and $(2, 4)$ are two such pairs, and $N$ is $4$, then the possible groups are $(1), (2), (3), (4), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)$.

Note that $(1,3)$ cannot be combined not only because of the constraint, but they have a difference of greater than $1$. Similarly $(2,4)$.

I tried for a few hours and found a pattern that goes like this:

- Let's say the number of ways $1$ can be grouped, is $1$ because the only way is to have a single integer in the group.
- For $2$, it does not have a conflict with $1$, so we can say, $2$ ways.
- For $3$, it has a conflict with $1$, and since it has a difference greater than $1$ from $1$, the number of ways is the same as that for $(2). i.e.  2$ ways.
- For $4$, we have a conflict with $2$, so the number of ways is the same as for $(3). i.e. 2$ ways.
- (If the adjacent numbers have a conflict, then we decrease the number of ways by $1$.)

As a whole, it gives $1+2+2+2 = 7$ ways.

The above method works but how can we represent the number of ways in a mathematical way? (Possibly with a proof)

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  There are $N$ single element groups and $N-1$ consecutive pairs, yes?  If you exclude some of these then there are fewer.  What's the question?

Comment: I guess I am not sure what you mean by "you are to group".   Suppose $N=5$ and that there are no extra exclusions.  Is the answer $5+(5-1)=9$ or is it something else?

Comment: Some of the other possible pairs are $(1,2,3,4)$ which is not valid because $(1,3)$ or  $(2,4)$ shouldn't be in the same group, and $(2,3,4)$ is invalid because $(2,4)$ for the same reason.

Comment: As I say, this is not clear at all.  Do you agree with my formula (with no extra restrictions)?  I get $2N-1$.  Sure gives $7$ in the case $N=4$.

Comment: @lulu, $N = 5$ and there are no exclusions, then there would be $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15$ groups.

Comment: I have no idea where $15$ comes from.  Please list all $15$ groups.  Or at least give an example of one good group that isn't in my list of $9$.

Comment: $(1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5), (1,2,3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)$

Comment: But the group $(1,2,3,4,5)$ contains $1,3$ which are not adjacent.  So you allow consecutive strings of arbitrary length?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didn't mention in the question. I will edit it right away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77763/discussion-between-raghav-and-lulu).

Comment: In any case, it would be appear that for each $i$ you should define $n_i$, the least number with $n≥n_i>i$ and $(i,n_i)$ excluded.  Then you can have $n_i-1$ strings starting at $i$.  You answer is then $\sum ((n_i-i)+1)$.

Comment: Sorry:  should have written that as $(1,n_{i}+1)$ excluded.  Since $(1,n+1)$ is always excluded this definition works in all cases.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm dumb. Can you please explain?  Sorry

Comment: Well, I think I was too hasty.  If $(2,4)$ is excluded then I can't have $(1,2,3,4)$ even if $(1,4)$ was not specifically excluded.  So you have to redefine my $n_i$ to exclude that as well.  Easy to do algorithmically, but I don't think it lends itseld to a useful formula.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Can you give an insight into the mathematical explanation of the algorithm? I implemented the algorithm which works fine but I have no idea of the math behind it.